# RAILS 4 to_json include on multiple vars

Tags: ruby, json, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I can `:include` assiciations to json-response using `to_json` like so:

```
def stats
  @orders = Order.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @orders.to_json(:include => :review) }
  end
end
```

It works okay, **but what if I need associations on multiple variables?**

This:

```
def stats
  @orders = Order.all
  @tasks = Task.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => {
        orders: @orders.to_json(:include => :review),
        tasks: @tasks.to_json(:include => :user)
      }
    }
  end
end
```

is not working – it's returning a string instead of json:
[image]

Comment: you can use `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(orders)`

Comment: So it would be kind of `encode { decode(enconde(orders)) }`?

Comment: when you do `to_json` it converts the object in json string so to convert it you need to decode it

Comment: thanks for the solution, even though it seems too hacky. Are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the situation where the [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) kicks in, which comes as a default ruby gem in Rails 4

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. see the following example

**e.g.**

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(orders)
```

To decode the Json string in to Hash.

Comment: turns out there is a cleaner solution, in case you are interested, which is `jbuilder`